# Webview auto zoom IN to fit screen

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I've made an Android App that's simply a wrapper around a mobile website.
Now some users complain that the "little" site is to small for a bigger screen/resolution.
I'd try to "autozoom" the site a little bit so it would fit better, this seems to work pretty decent. But sometimes the site does not wrap and so a part of the zoomed page falls of the screen.
I use this to set the zoom-level:

```
oWebView.setInitialScale(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.zoom));
```

In the HTML i've put:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

It's a bit hard to test, but with some AVD's set to diffirent resolutions I can get a long way.

Anyone else got a smarter way of doing this?
All the topics i've found are for zooming OUT so the entire site fits the webview.
I want to zoom IN so the top-left part of the site fits better, but don't want to scroll horizontal. So after the zoom the site had to wrap (like when I use the zoomin controls)

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

The Overview mode will take care of autozooming the page to fit the screen - creating overview. ViewViewport disables the mobile phone fitting and says the page that it has width as normal browser.

Comment: some further commentary would help this answer